# Why won't Remmina connect to Windows 10 Remote Desktop?

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, remmina

I am running Windows 10 with remote desktop enabled on one machine and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I am trying to open connection from Ubuntu to Windows via Remmina Remote desktop, Remmina's window minimizing as if connection will be established soon and nothing happening then.

No error message appears.

How to fix?

Answer (score 6):

I install Remmina-Next in Ubuntu 16.04.3 in one command line:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

(after this reboot)

Remmina-Next offers the latest features and the package maintainers are attentive. Any issues you experience can be reported here:
https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/

Comment: As of 2023, Doing the above on a W10 WSL2 Debian install, worked.

Answer (score 3):

It was because I changed password on Windows box. More precisely, I changed Windows authentication from Microsoft account to local account. Apparently Remmina has no error message for this.

Comment: You may experience [other issues](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/1513) soon, if you haven't yet (Due to Windows 10 Update).

Comment: @LonnieBest software becomes more and more unusable each new version, have you noticed? If I don't use my notebook for a month, I need hours to make it work again.

Comment: Breakage is fairly rare on what I'm running: Ubuntu 16.04.3. If you wait a month to use your laptop, I'd do an Ubuntu Update first recent login. BTW, that issue I mentioned has been fixed in Remmina-Next.